# Длина GET Запроса

Tags: jquery, get, http, javascript

Здравствуйте, столкнулся со следующей проблемой.

У меня есть некоторое `API` которому можно передавать `GET` Запросы. Для взаимодействия с ним используется `jQuery`. Есть функция постинга новости, и если ее текст достаточно велик, то запрос отклоняется сервером.

Например `[GET] api.php?m=post_news&text=%очень много букв%`
Переходить на `POST` обязательно, или можно обойти ограничение? И поможет ли сам переход. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Вот отличный ответ на ваш вопрос: [What is the maximum possible length of a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string)
2. `GET` — "получение" данных, `POST` — "сохранение" (каждый тип запроса нужен для определенной задачи/цели, вот и  используйте их по назначению).

Comment: а если это получение данных, например фильтр по многим полям который может не поместится get запрос тогда что?

Comment: @EmirMamashov значит при проектировании вы допустили ошибку и вам нехватает длинны дерева со всех окресных лесов чтобы  сделать дверь в дом(отгадка: потолки высоковаты)